# Java several constructors with one parameter in each and different type

Tags: java

I'm facing a problem with constructors.

```
public abstract class ShapeDrawer implements iShapeDrawer {

    protected SimpleLine line; // the line to be drawn
    protected SimpleOval oval; // the oval to be drawn
    protected SimpleTriangle triangle; // the triangle to be drawn
    protected SimplePolygon rectangle; // the triangle to be drawn

    public ShapeDrawer(SimpleLine line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

    public ShapeDrawer(SimpleOval oval) {
        this.oval = oval;
    }

    public ShapeDrawer(SimpleTriangle triangle) {
        this.triangle = triangle;
    }

    public ShapeDrawer(SimplePolygon rectangle) {
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
    }
}
```

When I am trying to run, it goes to first constuctor and throws and error for every single constructor.

> error: incompatible types: SimpleOval cannot be converted to SimpleLine
>           super(oval);

And that is the bit from Oval class

```
public class OvalDrawer extends ShapeDrawer implements iShapeDrawer{

    public OvalDrawer(SimpleOval oval) {
        super(oval);
    }
}
```

And I have SimpleShape class, which is a parent class of SimpleOval, SimpleLine and etc. and has all the methods. 
Example of SimpleOval

```
public class SimpleOval extends SimpleShape {

public SimpleOval(int xStart, int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd, Color colour, int thickness, ShapeType shapeType) {
    super(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd, colour, thickness, shapeType);   
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a note, `OvalDrawer` doesn't have to implement `iShapeDrawer`, because it extends `ShapeDrawer` which already implements this interface.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.

Comment: My suggestion would be to have a shape-specific implementation of `ShapeDrawer` for each of the `SimpleLine`, `SimpleOval` etc classes.

Comment: Did you compile `OvalDrawer`, and then go back and add more constructors to `ShapeDrawer` without recompiling `OvalDrawer`? That's the only way I can think to contrive this problem.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest to make the `ShapeDrawer` generic, with a type-parameter some subclass of `Shape`:

```
public abstract class ShapeDrawer<T extends Shape> implements iShapeDrawer {
    protected T shape; //the shape to be drawn

    public ShapeDrawer(T shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }
}
```

Then, each of the different shapes will have a corresponding `ShapeDrawer` class. For example, the `SimpleOval` would be drawn with:

```
public class SimpleOvalDrawer extends ShapeDrawer<SimpleOval> {
    public SimpleOvalDrawer(SimpleOval oval) {
        super(oval);
    }
}
```

Similar classes should be introduced for the other `Shape` sub-types.

There's also no need `SimpleOvalDrawer` to explicitly implement the `iShapeDrawer` interface, as `ShapeDrawer` already does.

Comment: The drawer should draw shapes, and should not be their super-class. That's what I think. :)

Comment: I have tried your solution, did not work. I have updated some information on my post. It may be a change